# Evitar espacios en blanco javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Hola amigos tengo este código que sirve para validar campos de texto en js.

```js
const nombre=document.querySelector('#nombre').value,
          empresa=document.querySelector('#empresa').value,
          telefono=document.querySelector('#telefono').value,
          accion=document.querySelector('#accion').value;

     if(nombre==='' || empresa==='' || telefono===''){
          mostrarNotificacion('Hubo un error', 'error');
     }
```

No obstante cuando en mi formulario introduzco espacios en blancos se modifica la base de datos y eso quiero cambiarlo. Es como si el input.value fuera igual a "  ". Como puedo evitar por completo que un campo vacío se inserte en la base de datos sin tener que colocar el required como atributo?

Answer (score 2):

Saludos podrias hacer algo como esto:

```js
function validar(){
  var nombre   = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
  if(nombre.trim() == '' || nombre == null){
   alert('ingrese el nombre');
    return false;
  }
  var apellido  = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
  if(apellido.trim() == '' || apellido == null){
   alert('ingrese el apellido');
    return false;
  }
  var data = {
   nombre:nombre.trim(),
   apellido:apellido.trim()
  }
  console.log(data);
}//end function validar
```

```html
<label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
<input type="text" id="nombre" value="Diego    "><br><br>

<label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
<input type="text" id="apellido" value="Avila      "><br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Validar" onclick="validar();">
```

Si te fijas por defecto cargo dos input con valores y espacios en blanco, lo que hago es obtener los valores de los mismos mediante su **ID** con esto en un if valido que no este vacio ni nulo sus valores si lo estan muestro una alerta, mas abajo armo la DATA que necesito y remuevo los espacios tanto de inicio como del final con **trim**

Espero te sirva de guia y suerte..!!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que encontré un método que me ayuda: trim();

Comment: favor de leer [answer], la idea de colocar respuestas es explicar como esto da solución a tu problema

Answer (score 0):

si quiere evita el envió de datos vacíos puede utilizar el atributo required para verificar si los campos no este vació, aqui tiene un ejemplo, en caso de que necesite verificar mas valiaciones puede utilizar la funcion onsubmit si desea mejorar las validaciones

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="myFunction()">
  nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" required><br>
  empresar: <input type="text" name="empresar" required><br>
  telefono: <input type="text" name="telefono" required><br>
  
<input type="submit">
</form> 

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("se envio los datos");
}
</script>
```